# What do the Devas do with offerings of sacrificial blood in Yajnas?

Tags: shiva, yajna, vedic-rituals, ashwamedha

It is known that whatever is offered to the Devas in Yajnas is consumed by them. So things like milk, butter, ghee, soma, meat, liquor etc are all eaten and drank by the Devas.

For example, Vyasa smriti says:

> Milk, wine, honey, and clarified butter are the articles which the gods are fond of... (38)

However, in the Ashwamedha yajna, after the horse is killed, its blood is offered to Rudra in the Agni fire.

> He offers the first oblation of blood by means of the gullet of the gomrga. The gomrga is cattle, and the Agni Svistakrt is Rudra. He thus shields the cattle from Rudra. And in the country where this libation is offered, Rudra does not attempt to injure the cattle.

What do Rudra and the Devas do with offerings of sacrificial blood in Yajnas? Do they consume it like the other offerings?